# EF Core generating query with declared variables

Tags: sql-server, ef-core-3.1

When using EF Core with SQL Server for query, the generated SQL uses `DECLARE` variables.

That changes the execution plan to use a different index altogether.

For example - this is my code:

```
Set<Order>().Where(x => x.DueDate >= fromDate && x.DueDate <= toDate).ToList()
```

where `Order` is an entity with indexes on `ID` column (`IX_ID`) and index on `DueDate` column (`IX_DUEDATE`).

EF Core generates a query:

```
DECLARE @__fromDate_1 datetime2 = '2023-11-23T00:00:00.0000000';
DECLARE @__toDate_2 datetime2 = '2023-11-28T00:00:00.0000000';

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [o]
WHERE [o].[DueDate] >= @__fromDate_1 AND [o].[Due] <= @__toDate_2
```

This does an INDEX SCAN on `IX_ID` (index on ID).

The execution plan of the above is very different from say a query like

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Orders o 
WHERE o.DueDate BETWEEN '2023-11-23' AND '2023-11-28';
```

This does an INDEX SEEK on the index `IX_DUEDATE`.

How can I get EF Core to generate variables inline instead of declaring them separately?

I have tried generating execution plans of the actual SQL query that I wanted and the SQL generated by EF Core. The execution plans are different.

The execution plan of the desired query results in INDEX SEEK on an INDEX.

The execution plan of the EF Core query results in INDEX SCAN on the primary key.

Comment: Generating queries with "inlining" the values (as you do) will results in poor query execution plan reuse - each and every single query will need to be prepared, and will cause a new, separate execution plan to be generated and stored. This will affect your SQL Server performance in a very bad way - the way EF Core goes is the much better approach - one query, one query plan, just replacing the parameters with actual values for each execution

Comment: First of all, EF Core 3.1 is no longer supported. Use EF Core 6 at least. Second, the duplicate shows that you can force EF Core to generate values instead of parameters if you include the values in the query instead of using variables. The problem itself is called "parameter sniffing"

Comment: @marc_s after "inlining" the values, SQL Mgmt Studio shows the execution plans using INDEX SEEK which is much better than an execution plan using INDEX SCAN.

Comment: @saudansari: not necessarily - espeially if you take into account that with inlining, every query must be optimized, a plan must be found and determined, and then executed. Yes, maybe the execution time is better - but if every single query needs to be parsed and a plan devised for it, overall it will be worse. Not to mention the load you're putting onto the plan cache, filling it up with plan after plan after plan, one for each separate query...... not a good idea overall and long-term